# duplicate file descriptor to point to pipe

Tags: c, file-descriptor

My program will pick a random number and have the use guess what it is. I am almost done with it, except I need to duplicate the file descriptors to point to a pipe, and I'm not entirely sure how to do that. I think i'd have to use dup2, but I'm not entirely sure how to implement it. Anything helps. Here is my code so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
  int pid;
  int n;
  char buf[101];
  int pfdA[2];
  int pfdB[2];

  // CREATE FIRST PIPE
  if (pipe(pfdA) == -1)
  {
    perror("pipe failed");
    exit(-1);
  }

  // CREATE SECOND PIPE
  if (pipe(pfdB) == -1)
  {
    perror("pipe failed");
    exit(-1);
  }

  // FORK()
  if ((pid == fork()) < 0)
  {
    perror("fork failed");
    exit(-2);
  }

  if (pid == 0)
  {
    // duplicate file descriptor 0 to point to FIRST pipe

    // CLOSE ends of FIRST pipe you don't need anymore
    close(pfdA[0]);
    close(pdfA[1]);

    // duplicate file descriptor 1 to point to SECOND pipe

    // CLOSE ends of SECOND pipe you don't need anymore
    close(pfdB[0]);
    close(pfdB[1]);

    execlp("./A5_CHILD", "./A5_CHILD", (char *) 0);
    perror("execlp");
    exit(-3);
  }

  else
  {

    while (1)
    {
      char NUM[100];
      close(pfdA[0]);
      close(pfdB[1]);

      int r = 0;

      printf("Enter a Number: ");
      fflush(stdout);
      scanf("%s", NUM);

      // SEND   NUM   to Child process
      write(pdfA[1], NUM, strlen(NUM));

      // READ FROM CHILD THE RESPONSE into the variable buf and
      //      store the return value from read() into the variable r
      r = read(pfdB[0], buf, 100);

      if (r > 0)
      {
        buf[r] = '\0';
        printf("%s\n", buf);
        fflush(stdout);
      }
      else
      {
        printf("[PARENT] Reading from child: read() returned %d\n", r);
        break;
      }
    }
  }

  return (0);
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to setup a chain of child-processes, each of which pulls data from the prior (except the first one), then munches on it and feed data to the next, until the last one which sends the final data back to the parent, and in doing so, how to setup the io pipes using `dup2()` ?

Comment: @WhozCraig it would be just one child and one parent, but the child process is the one that runs the program that actually plays the game. So it needs to be able to give and receive a number through the pipe. But yes, I need to know how to set up the pipes using dup2() I beleive, unless there is a better way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

> I think i'd have to use dup2, but I'm not entirely sure how to
>   implement it.

You are right.

```
    // duplicate file descriptor 0 to point to FIRST pipe
    dup2(pfdA[0], 0);
```

...

```
    // duplicate file descriptor 1 to point to SECOND pipe
    dup2(pfdB[1], 1);
```